# Как добавлять компоненты? Angular Material

Tags: typescript, angular, angular-material

Создал проект, решил добавить некоторые компоненты Material Angular.

```
ng add @angular/material
```

После этого добавил новый модуль Material

```
ng g m material
```

Добавил модули кнопок и чекбоксов в material.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';

const MaterialComponents = [
  MatButtonModule,
  MatCheckboxModule
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [MaterialComponents],
  exports: [MaterialComponents]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

В app.module добавил MaterialModule

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';    
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NavigationHeaderComponent } from './navigation-header/navigation-header.component';
import { TodoComponent } from './todo/todo.component';
import { MaterialModule } from './material/material.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavigationHeaderComponent,
    TodoComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Создал компонент todo

```
ng g c todo
```

В todo.component.ts добавил импорт кнопки

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatButton } from '@angular/material/button';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo',
  templateUrl: './todo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo.component.css']
})
export class TodoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

HTML компонента todo

```
<div class="container">
    <p>TODO LIST</p>
    <button mat-button>Click me!</button>
</div>
```

В итоге: кнопка есть, но не как Material. Кнопки Material работают, если добавлять их в app.component.html, необходимо добавить их в созданный компонент. Подскажите пожалуйста, что делаю не так или подскажите как правильно?

Comment: для того. чтобы сказать что ты делаешь не так, ты должен [создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в MaterialModule в import и export передать не массив массивов, а просто массив.
Тоесть с

imports: [MaterialComponents],
  exports: [MaterialComponents]

в

imports: MaterialComponents,
  exports: MaterialComponents

Comment: массивы флаттанятся при компиляции, поэтому это не имеет значения

Comment: Если бы это влияло на что-то, то у меня в app.component.html тоже не работало бы. Но оно там работает, а в созданных компонентах нет.

Answer (score 0):

У меня была точно такая же ситуация. Проблема была из-за того, что компонент, в котором я хотел использовать Material, находился в другом модуле (AuthModule). И этот модуль нужно было подключить в app.module.ts. Подключил, и все заработало. В моем случае подключил вот так:

```
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';

@NgModule({ imports: [ AuthModule]})
```

Также до этого в моем модуле (AuthModule) нужно было подключить MaterialModule таким же образом, как вы подключали его в app.module.ts

"В todo.component.ts добавил импорт кнопки" - а вот это, по моему, вообще ни на что не влияет.